# Towers of Hanoi non recursive: Is my code correct?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written the following code for Towers of Hanoi problem using non recursive approach. I guess it is not correct as the number of moves are not 2**n - 1, for eg, for 3 disks to be moved, it has to generate 7 moves. Thanks in advance.

```
######################
#   Towers of Hanoi  #
######################

numbers = []

def TowersofHanoi():
# Proram to simulate Towers of hanoi
# Objective is to move the disks from A to C 
# with B as a temporary varialbel


    print "Program to simulate Towers of Hanoi"
    print "Users will input numbers of disks, which is 'A'"
    print "The disks have to be moved from A to C"
    print "With B as temporary placeholder"


    print "Enter the number of disks to be moved:",

    Num = int (raw_input("> "))
    Src = Num
    Aux = 0
    Dst = 0
    print "you have entered %d disks to be moved"
    print "Source is -->", Src
    print "Auxillary is -->", Aux
    print "Destination is -->", Dst


    print "Disk positions after the placement:"

    #B = A-1
    #print B
    while Num >= 1: 
        print Num
        Aux = Num-1
        Src = Src-Aux   
        Dst = Src   

        print "Source is -->", Src
        print "Auxillary is -->", Aux
        print "Destination is -->", Dst
        Src = Aux
        Num = Num-1

        numbers.append(Dst)
    print numbers


    print "The task of accomplishing the movements of disk is over"
    print "This completes TOWERS OF HANOI!"
    print "Final disk positions are:"
    print "Source is -->", Src
    print "Auxillary is -->", Aux
    print "Destination is -->", len(numbers)

TowersofHanoi()
```

Comment: Have you tried matching this with an existing algorithm?

Comment: While matching this with the algorithm, i have found some issues with this.

Comment: i will edit my question.

Comment: I don't get where your "algorithm" is. At the moment you basically ask the user for moves and then do the moves. So far you neither check the validity of the moves (not every move is valid in this problem) nor do you have an algorithm generating moves. Do I miss something?

Comment: @Jakob S: thanks for pointing this, I wanted to know what I am missing. I am not checking for validity of moves, though I was able to figure out that I am not taking disk size into consideration.

Comment: Just as a heads up, variable names in Python should never be upper case, or CamelCased (this is reserved for classes). It's perfectly valid, but not convention. See [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions).

Answer (score 0):

I think your algorithm is fundamentally flawed (no offence):

```
Aux = Num-1
Src = Src-Aux   
Dst = Src
```

The way i read this, you take num-1 'rings' from the 'left' stack and put them on the 'middle' stack and then move the remaining rings from the 'lef' stack to the 'right' stack (the destination stack). I thought the way towers of Hanoi worked was moving 1 ring at a time?

Thus, in your case, when Num = 3, Aux = 2 after 1 move, which shouldn't be possible.

Maybe have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Iterative_solution
it describes the towers of hanoi problem in many different forms.

Comment: I know that it is flawed indeed, and that's what i want to know where am I going wrong. Infact, I want to know how to get the legal moves check. Thanks

Comment: I believe that recursive solution would generate the correct solution for Towers of Hanoi. I will do it on my own. Thanks.